# Python 3.6+, change representation of None in file

Tags: python, csv, serialization, null, nonetype

I have to extract from several sources and save the result to csv files.  When the data received for a field is `None`, I want it represented as empty string.  (I realize I'll lose the distinction between empty string and NULL-type values in the source.)

My underlying requirement is to preserve the distinction between the string "None" and nothingness in a plain delimited file, without using quotes.

I hope to **avoid calling a function that checks if a value is null for every nullable field** I write, or at least have that call not explicit in the code... e.g., I want to just code `f.write(row['LastName']`, and if the LastName is "None" get "None", but if it is of `NoneType` get an empty string.

I haven't yet investigated if the comes-with csv library can do what I need, I will do that, it seems likely that's the easiest approach.

But: is there anything I can override, so that if I write `None` to a file, I get empty string (or something besides the string "None" in the output file?

It seems to me I'd have to change either 1) the built-in write method of `_io.TextIOWrapper` or 2) the `__str__` method of the `NoneType`.

Comment: once I say ```open(filename, 'wt`) as f``` -- is there away to attach a new method to "f", and call that method instead of ```write```?

Comment: [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) automatically converts `None` to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`if row['LastName'] is None` will check if your value is a `NoneType`

Something like:

```
if row['LastName'] is None:
    f.write("")
else:
    f.write(row['LastName'])
```

Would get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't check each field (at least on the "surface" of the code).  I edited my question to put emphasis on that.